# Save changes after drag n drop in TreeList

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, devexpress, treelist

The drag-n-drop works in Treelist, but I don't know how to save them so when I close/open my project, it reverts to the old values in Treelist. For example i move the rows up or down but when i open project again reverts the old position

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        treeList1.OptionsDragAndDrop.DragNodesMode = checkBox1.Checked ? DragNodesMode.Single : DragNodesMode.None;
    }
    //</checkBox1>

    private DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode GetDragNode(IDataObject data)
    {
        return data.GetData(typeof(DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode)) as DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode;
    }

    //<listBox1>
    private string GetStringByNode(DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode node)
    {
        string ret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < treeList1.Columns.Count; i++)
            ret += node.GetDisplayText(i) + (i < treeList1.Columns.Count - 1 ? "; " : ".");
        return ret;
    }

    private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetDragNode(e.Data) != null)
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.ListBoxControl lb = sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.ListBoxControl;
        DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode node = GetDragNode(e.Data);
        if (node != null)
        {
            string dragString = GetStringByNode(node);
            int ind = lb.IndexFromPoint(lb.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
            if (ind == -1)
                lb.Items.Add(dragString);
            else
                lb.Items.Insert(ind, dragString);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TreeList saves changes caused by moving a node to another parent node since this node's **ParentID** field is updated correspondingly. However, if you move a node within the same child node collection, these changes will be lost. That is why to accomplish this task, you need to create an additional datasource column that will store the current index of each node. This approach is illustrated in the [How to change a TreeList node position along with a corresponding record's position in the database](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3577/how-to-change-a-treelist-node-position-along-with-a-corresponding-record-s-position-in) example. Take a look at it.